# How to align three ImageViews horizontally in Android?

Tags: android

I want to show three `ImageViews` at the bottom of the screen with equal weight. But the size of the images is not fixed. I want to show 2 images and one should be hidden, what should I do?
How to adjust the space in between three `ImageViews` which should be side by side of each other, and the 3rd `ImageView` should not overlap the two `ImageViews` which are visible on the screen?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/main_imge_1"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="#F9F939"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_toLeftOf ="@+id/imageView6"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="15dp" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#54F71D"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1DF7AB"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:padding="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Dear user, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the first lines of your question aloud and tell me if you understand them. Then, please explain them to me - especially the last sentence.

Comment: What are you trying to say...write clearly please...

Comment: i want to show threeimageview horizonatlly at bottom of screen what do i do?

Comment: Basic Layout should be linear instead of relative. relative just causes trouble when you align stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F9F939"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#54F71D"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#1DF7AB"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Yeah ! Worked as expected ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what I was able to decrypt, you're probably trying to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F9F939"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F9F939"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#F9F939"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result:

[image]

The key is to use an enclosing `LinearLayout` to hold your `ImageView`s and having that `LinearLayout` aligned to Bottom in your `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:layout_weight="1" for each ImageView. And replace your RelativeLayout to Linearlayout.